# How to Fix the Logic Errors in My "Guess the Movie" Game as a C Program

Tags: c, logic

I have written a *Guess the Movie* game in the C programming language. My logic seems to be correct but whenever I run the program, it doesn't work as expected.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int ran = 1;
    int l, j = 0, i = 0, total = 0, d = 0;
    char b;
    char a[20];
    char s[1000];
    int z;
    FILE *my;

    printf("Enter your name:\n ");
    scanf("%s", s);

    ran = rand() % 6;
    if (ran == 1)
    {
        my = fopen("my1.txt", "r");
    }
    else if (ran == 2)
    {
        my = fopen("my.txt", "r");
    }
    else if (ran == 3)
    {
        my = fopen("my2.txt", "r");
    }
    else if (ran == 4)
    {
        my = fopen("my3.txt", "r");
    }
    else if (ran == 5)
    {
        my = fopen("my4.txt", "r");
    }

    for (d = 0; d < 20; d++)
        fscanf(my, "%c", &a[d]);

    fclose(my);

    printf("GUESS THE MOVIE GAME\n");

    for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        if (a[j] == 'm')
        {
            printf("M ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("_ ");
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Let's begin the game\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 7;)
    {             
        if (a[i] != 'm')
        {
            printf("enter character number %d\n",i+1);
            scanf("%c", &b);
            if (b == a[i])
            {
                printf("its a right guess\n");
                total = total + 4;
                i++;
            }
            else if (b != a[i])
            {
                printf("Wrong choice\n");
                if (total == 1 || total == 0)
                {
                    total=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    total = total - 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("You have guessd the movie\n");
    printf("The movie name is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("%c",a[i]);
    }
    printf("Your score is %d\n",total);
}
```

This is the program output that I get each time I run the above code:

> Enter your name:
>    raj
>   GUESS THE MOVIE GAME
>   _ _ _ _ M _ _
>   Let's begin the game
>   Enter character number 1
>   Wrong choice
>   Enter character number 1
>   I
>   Wrong choice
>   Enter character number 1
>   Wrong choice
>   Enter character number 1

Comment: Is this wavy indentation intended? Sorry, we can't read code like this.

Comment: try printing ran out when it's generated.

Comment: Notes: `ran=rand()%6;` gives `6` different values but you only make decisions to open `5` files. What will happen when `ran == 0`? Also, you'll use the same question list every time until you add `srand((unsigned)time(NULL))` at the top of `main()`. And please change the occurrences of `"%c"` to `" %c"` to filter newlines which are left in the input buffer.

Comment: Re-worded the question text. Formatted the C code.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", s);`  1) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  In this case: `if( scanf("%s", s) != 1 ) { // handle error }  2) the input format specifier: `%s` (and `[...]`) always append a NUL byte to the input.  To avoid possible buffer overflow and resulting undefined behavior, always use a MAX CHARACTER modifier that is 1 less than the input buffer length. In this case: `scanf("%999s", s);`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) insert a space: inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) single character variable names, like 's' and 'a', etc are meaningless, even in the current context. Strongly suggest using meaningful variable names

Comment: regarding statements like: `scanf("%c", &b);`  when using the '%c' and/or '%[...]'  input format specifiers, always insert a leading space in the format string to consume any left over 'white space'  in `stdin`

Comment: OT:  This statement: `else if (b != a[i])` can be reduced to `else` as a value is either equal or not equal and the `equal` check was already done in the prior `if()`

Comment: OT: regarding; `if (ran == 1)` and the rest of that `if`/`else if` sequence, It would be MUCH clearer and cleaner to use a `switch` statement

Comment: before calling `rand()`, always (and only once) call `srand()` otherwise that same sequence will always be returned from `rand()`

Comment: regarding: `for (d = 0; d < 20; d++)
        fscanf(my, "%c", &a[d]);`  What if the file contains less than 20 characters?  What if the file contains less than 7 characters?  Also, as mentioned in a prior comment,  as with all the `scanf()` family of functions: always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: How do you deduce "My logic seems to be correct" from "whenever I run the program, it doesn't work as expected"?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the deficiencies pointed out in comments, there's this major logic error:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 7;)
    {             
        if (a[i] != 'm')
        {
            …
        }
    }
```

If the loop encounters an `m`, it repeats endlessly. Eliminate the `if (a[i] != 'm')` or add an `else ++i`.